# There exists a regular language A such that for all languages B, A ∩ B is regular.

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language

> There exists a regular language A such that for all languages B, A ∩ B
>   is regular.

The above given statement is true but I couldn't make any proof or find any proof. It is an objective type question asked [here](http://quiz.geeksforgeeks.org/gate-gate-cs-2016-set-2-question-52/) to find whether the given statement is true or false. I want to know how to conclude this given statement is true.

Comment: There exists **infinite** regular languages $A$ such that for all languages $B$, $A \cap B$ is regular.   Take any finite $A \subseteq \Sigma^*$.

Comment: @Bakuriu You probably meant the opposite of your first sentence.

Comment: @6005 It depends on how you parse that sentence. It should be read as $\exists^{\infty} A ....$ (there exist an infinite number of languages $A$ such that) not $\exists A, |A|=\infty ...$ (there exists one language, which is infinite, ..)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, that's true. Consider $A=\emptyset$ (which is regular), then $\emptyset \cap B=\emptyset$ (which is regular).

Answer (score 25):

If $A$ is a finite language, then it is regular and meets your condition.

On the other hand if $A$ is any infinite regular language, since it is countably infinite ($\aleph_0$) it will contain $\aleph_1$ sublanguages. Every regular language is defined by a finite regular expression (of which there are $\aleph_0$) so there will be sublanguages of $A$ which is not regular.

So finiteness is necessary and sufficient.

Comment: Note that your answer depends on the continuum hypothesis. You probably just meant "uncountably many" which is all you need for your argument, but without irrelevant assumptions, you would have $2^{\aleph_0}$ sublanguages.

Comment: Rule of thumb: Unless you're playing around with the CH or the ordinals, you want either [beth numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beth_number) or some expression involving $\aleph_0$.

Comment: @Richard: Or simply ‘at least $\aleph_1$’, though I too would prefer ‘uncountably many’ here, since that gets directly to the essential point.

Comment: As a constructive way to make a nonregular sublanguage, take all the sentences, order them by length, then take a subsequence where the length grows too quickly to be regular.

Comment: @Owen that is really slick. Is it correct to say that if a regular language that has a finite automata on $n$ states and is not finite, for every valid word $w$ there is a valid word $w'$ with $|w| < |w'| < |w| + n$?

Comment: @YBerman That sounds right to me.

Comment: @YBerman the second $<$ should be $\leq$ - think about automata for $a^n$